# How can I check if the elements of an ArrayList equal another value in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist, multidimensional-array

Specifically if said `ArrayList` is made out of String elements, and I'd like to check each letter in those `Strings`. This is what I tried, but obviously it doesn't work:

```
public void fillBoard()
    {
        board = new char[ROW][COL];

        for (String s: words){

            for(int rows = 0; rows < board.length; rows++)
            {
                for(int cols = 0; cols < board[rows].length; cols++)
                {
                    if(!s.equals(board[rows][cols])) 
                    {                          
                        board[rows][cols] = randomChar();
                    }
                }   

            }
        }
    }
```

I was trying to compare each char in a `2D` array to the letters in the `Strings` that make up the `ArrayList`.

The `ArrayList` is `ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();` and it's populated by the users as they enter words when prompted. So it can look like {"hello","goodbye","words",...}

`board` is a 2D char array, the dimensions are defined by user input

It's then populated by random chars by this method:

```
public char randomChar()
    {
        char alphabet[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k',
                'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x',
                'y', 'z'};

        return alphabet[(char)(alphabet.length * Math.random())];
    }

}
```

The intention is that the `char board[][]` array may also contain randomly placed words, and when the board is updated, all the letters that aren't part of a `string` in the `words ArrayList` are randomized again, keeping the words that the user input and where then placed in the array, kind of like updating the board in a battleship program after each turn.

Comment: convert your string into a char array and then try to compare and by the way you are comparing your complete string with every character of 2d array, its never gonna work with this logic, compare a row with string

Comment: You reinitialize your char array, so it's never gonna work. Give some more info on input data, maybe provide a sample so we could help.

Comment: @Default71721 I added some extra info

Answer (score 1):

You are directly **comparing the string with a character** which needs to be changed and look at the below steps:

(1) Iterate each row of the `char` array

(2) Get the `string` from `list`

(3) Now Iterate across the columns of the array and compare with each character in the `string`

(4) At each step, I have added validations to check if they are comparable in length and `break`, if not, you can actually modify this according to your requirement.

You can refer the below code with inline comments:

```
public static void fillBoard() {
        int x=2;//change row size accordingly
        int y=2;//change row size accordingly
        char[][] board = new char[x][y];
        //load the board char array

        List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
        //load the list

        //Iterate each row of the char array
        for(int rows = 0; rows < board.length; rows++) {
            //Check if list size is correct to compare
            if(rows >= words.size()) {
                System.out.println("list size is lower than 
                   the array size,can't caompare these rows");
                break;
            }
            //Get the string from list
            String s = words.get(rows);

            //Iterate across the columns and compare with string character
            for(int cols = 0; cols < board[rows].length; cols++) {
                //check if string length is comparable
                if(s.length() != board[rows].length) {
                    System.out.println("list string length is lower
                         than the array string length,can't caompare ");
                    break;
                }
                if(s.charAt(cols) != board[rows][cols]) {                          
                    System.out.println(s.charAt(cols)+" is different !!!");
                    board[rows][cols] = randomChar();
                }
            }   
        }
    }
```